# How to create AES key and encrypt it by private Key on Android API 22?

Tags: java, android, encryption, android-room

I know there are many posts on this subject, however the security of cryptography is changing every year and I want to make sure my application is safe.
I want to **create** an **AES key** that will encrypt my database (SQLCipher). Then this key will be **encrypted** by the generated **public key** and **kept** in **SharedPreferences** (EncryptedSharedPreferences itroduced in Api23).
I know that now are better options for that, but minimum required SDK is 23 (mine is 22)...
So i trying everything.
Does the code I wrote meet today's security requirements?

**Generating key pair**

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(Constants.AndroidKeyStore);
            keyStore.load(null);
            if (keyStore.getKey(Constants.KEY_ALIAS, null) == null) {
                Calendar notBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar notAfter = Calendar.getInstance();
                notAfter.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
                KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = null;
                spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                        .setAlias("QWEKey")
                        .setKeySize(2048)
                        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=MyCompany"))
                        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                        .setStartDate(notBefore.getTime())
                        .setEndDate(notAfter.getTime())
                        .build();
                KeyPairGenerator generator = null;
                try {
                    generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
                    generator.initialize(spec);
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                generator.generateKeyPair();
            }
            return keyStore;
```

Now, creating **AES key**:

```
// check if encrypted AES key is in SharedPreferences
String encryptedKeyB64 = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.ENCRYPTED_KEY, null);
            if (encryptedKeyB64 == null || encryptedKeyB64.equals("")) {
// if not - create new AES key
            byte[] key = new byte[16];
            SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        secureRandom.nextBytes(key);

        byte[] encryptedKey = new byte[0];
        try {
// encrypt AES key (method below)
            encryptedKey = rsaEncrypt(mKeyStore, key);
            Log.d(TAG, "getEncryptedKeyB64: encryptedKey: " + encryptedKey.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
// save encrypted key in sharedPreferences
        encryptedKeyB64 = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.d(TAG, "getEncryptedKeyB64: encryptedKey64: (NEW) " + encryptedKeyB64);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit2 = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit2.putString(Constants.ENCRYPTED_KEY, encryptedKeyB64);
        edit2.apply();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "getEncryptedKeyB64: lenght: " + encryptedKeyB64.length());
    return encryptedKeyB64;
```

// (Edit) Now I'm using:

```
new MasterKey.Builder(context)
                    .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
                    .build();

EncryptedSharedPreferences
                    .create(
                            context,
                            ENCRYPTED_KEY,
                            masterKey,
                            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
                    );
```

method **rsaEncrypt():**

```
public static byte[] rsaEncrypt(KeyStore mKeyStore, byte[] secret) throws Exception{
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) mKeyStore.getEntry(Constants.KEY_ALIAS, null);

        // Encrypt the text
        Cipher inputCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Constants.RSA_MODE, "AndroidOpenSSL");
        inputCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey());
        Log.d(TAG, "rsaEncrypt: Certificates: " + privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getType()); // X.509
        Log.d(TAG, "rsaEncrypt: Certificates: " + privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey().toString());
        privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().verify(privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey());
        Log.d(TAG, "rsaEncrypt: Certificates: " + privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "rsaEncrypt: Certificates: " + Arrays.toString(privateKeyEntry.getCertificateChain()));

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, inputCipher);
        cipherOutputStream.write(secret);
        cipherOutputStream.close();

        byte[] vals = outputStream.toByteArray();
        Log.d(TAG, "rsaEncrypt: vals length: " + vals.length);
        return vals;
    }
```

**Now code for decrypt AES key and encrypt RoomDatabase:**

```
encrypted = Base64.decode(encryptedKeyB64, Base64.DEFAULT)

public static byte[] rsaDecrypt(KeyStore mKeyStore, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) mKeyStore.getEntry(Constants.KEY_ALIAS, null);
        Cipher output = Cipher.getInstance(Constants.RSA_MODE, "AndroidOpenSSL");
        output.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey());
        CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(encrypted), output);
        ArrayList<Byte> values = new ArrayList<>();
        int nextByte;
        while ((nextByte = cipherInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            values.add((byte)nextByte);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "rsaDecrypt: values lenght: " + values.size());
        byte[] bytes = new byte[values.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            bytes[i] = values.get(i).byteValue();
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

**And finally create encrypted database:**

```
final SupportFactory factory = new SupportFactory(decryptedKey);
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                ProductsDatabase.class, "ProductsDatabase")
                .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .openHelperFactory(factory)
                .build();
```

Comment: looks like this question may be a better fit for the codereview stackexchange

Comment: Note that version 1.1.0 of the androidx security library [supports API levels 21 and up](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data-android-versions) (though of course the AndroidKeyStore will only be used on OS versions that supports it).

Comment: You are creating an AES-key of 16 bytes / 128 bits length - if possible you should change this to 32 bytes / 256 bits length (I cannot check if the unlimited crypto is available on APP level 22/23). What is your chosen 'Constants.RSA_MODE' (some modes are better than others).

Comment: Thanks guys!
I added new edit to the post.
Thanks @Michael I can use MasterKey.Builder to create AES key 256bits, but how can i make it refer when i try to encrypt something? Where the key is saved?

Comment: @MichaelFehr i tried it - it works, but maybe better is Michael's solution?
RSA_MODE was "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"